# How to get single record from one to many relationship in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i have one to many relationship in my models and it works as i want, but sometime i only need one record to be returned (not as an array of collection). Here is my controller

```
$sesi = Sesi::with('jadwal.mapelLokal.guru','jadwal.mapelLokal.matapelajaran')->whereHas('jadwal',function($jadwal) use ($r) {
            $jadwal->whereHas('mapelLokal',function($mapel) use($r) {
                $mapel->where('id_lokal',$r->lokal);
            });
        })->get();
```

Sesi Model

```
class Sesi extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'sesi';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function jadwal()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('SIAStar\Jadwal','id_sesi');
    }
}
```

jadwal model

```
class Jadwal extends Model
{
    protected $table= 'jadwal';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function mapelLokal()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('SIAStar\MapelLokalGuru','id_mapel_lokal');
    }
}
```

and MapelLokalGuru

```
class MapelLokalGuru extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'mapel_lokal_guru';
    protected $fillable = ['id_lokal','mapel_id','guru_id'];
    public $timestamps=false;

    public function mataPelajaran()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('SIAStar\MataPelajaran','mapel_id');
    }
    public function guru()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('SIAStar\Guru','guru_id');
    }
    public function formNilai()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('SIAStar\FormNilai','id_mapel_lokal');
    }
    public function lokal()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('SIAStar\Lokal','id_lokal');
    }
    public function postMateri()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('SIAStar\PostKelasOnline','id_mapel_lokal');
    }
}
```

and the result of controller is like this

```
    Collection {#454 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => Sesi {#452 ▼
          #table: "sesi"
//...
          #relations: array:1 [▼
            "jadwal" => Collection {#468 ▼
              #items: array:1 [▶]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

as you se, jadwal relationship returning a collection, but what i want is only single record since it's only has one record. How to querying nested relationship so jadwal relationship only return one data?

Answer (score 0):

When you call the `jadwal` relationship, such as `$sesi->jadwal`, if you'd like to get only the first record, just call `first()`: `$sesi->jadwal->first()`.

If you'll *always* only want a single `jadwal` relationship, consider using `hasOne()` instead of `hasMany()`.

Comment: in some condition i also need jadwal to be returned as a collection, but in special case i only need one record, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to perform this task in laravel e.g.

1. Can use `take(1)` with builder to return only 1 record.
2. Can use `first()` to get first record.
3. Can use `latest() or oldest() or limit(1)` in relationship .

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask.

Comment: i know we can use first(), but can we use it inside the relationship?

Comment: you want in logic or in model where you specified the relationship. You can use at both places btw.

Comment: in logic, i need the perfect querybuilder for that

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need a single record from your table, it's advisable to use `value()` method from eloquent.

You might wanna look that up. Here is the [reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#retrieving-results)

Methods like `first()`, `latest()`, `oldest()` etc will still return the full row.

Alternatively, you could use `select('column_name_of_the_record')->first()` but I don't see why would you use it if you anyway got `value()`.

*I hope it helps*